# How to normalize all axis with batch normalization?

Tags: python, tensorflow, batch-normalization

As far as I understand, for `tf.layers.batch_normalization` the axis I define is the axis that gets normalized.

Simply put:

Given these values

```
a = [[0, 2], 
     [1, 4]]
```

with shape (2, 2) and therefore axis 0 and 1.

Normalizing over axis 1 would mean to reduce axis 0 to its mean and standard deviation and then take these values for the normalization.

Therefore

```
bn = tf.layers.batch_normalization(a, axis=[1])
```

would have (nearly) the same result as

```
m, v = tf.nn.moments(a, axes=[0])
bn = (a - m) / tf.sqrt(v)
```

But how would I do `tf.layers.batch_normalization` for all axis?

With the mean and standard deviation calculation from before this would be easy:

```
m, v = tf.nn.moments(a, axes=[0, 1])
bn = (a - m) / tf.sqrt(v)
```

But how to do this with batch normalization?

```
bn = tf.layers.batch_normalization(a, axis=[???])
```

I tried the following that doesn't work:

- `axis = None`: `AttributeError: 'BatchNormalization' object has no attribute 'axis'`
- `axis = []`: `IndexError: list index out of range`
- `axis = [0, 1]`: All results are zero

Comment: What is the usecase/advantage of such a batch normalization? Shouldn't normalisation be along the features axis first of all?

Comment: @NihalSangeeth You can normalize over what every axis you need to. It all depends how your data looks like and what it represents. Yes it is common to normalize over the feature axis but that doesn't exclude normalizing over any other dimension.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with [layer normalization](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LayerNormalization):

```
>>> data = tf.constant(np.arange(10).reshape(5, 2) * 10, dtype=tf.float32)
    layer = tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization(axis=[0, 1])
    output = layer(data)
    print(output)

tf.Tensor(
[[-1.5666981  -1.2185429 ]
 [-0.8703878  -0.5222327 ]
 [-0.17407757  0.17407756]
 [ 0.52223265  0.8703878 ]
 [ 1.2185429   1.5666981 ]], shape=(5, 2), dtype=float32)
```

The difference with batch normalization is that layer normalization applies the operation to each unit within a batch separately.

If you want to do this operation over a batch, go for batch norm though. Similarly this works by setting axis as a list.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't think this is feasable using the `batch_normalization` layers/function of the tensorflow API.

As the name of the function suggests, it's intended to perform "batch" normalization, so it's expected to normalize over the features axis given the current batch (usually dimension 0).

Comment: You could be right that the implementation doesn't allow a normalization over all axis. But the second part of your answer is not correct. Batch normalization only means that the mean, std as well as beta and gama are calculated over batches. This has nothing to do with the normalization process itself. It also doesn't predefine any axis. Yes it is common to normalize over the feature axis (which is normally -1 or 1; the 0 axis is the batch axis). But that doesn't mean that other use cases don't do batch normalization over other axis.